# Javascript code trying to be executed as php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, backbone.js, marionette

This is a wordpress plugin I've used Backbone Marionette to build the back-end.  The problem is that the template code (html and javascript) its being execute as php.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function substring() in ../main-menu.php on line 304

```
    <script type="text/template" id="amazon-result-item-view">
      <p class="small-text">
      <a href="<%= url %>" target="_blank" >
      <%= name.substring(0,30) %>...    //getting the php error at this line
      </a></p>

      <img width="100" src="<%= image_url %>" />
      <button data-product-index="<%= cid %>"
       class="tiny add-amazon-product">
      Add product</button>
    </script>
```

This is from a plugin that is working in several other WP sites my guess is that this one is parsing anything wrap by this <%= %> as php but not sure why...

Comment: Maybe try using `_.templateSettings` to set a different escape syntax? Example at http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@ivarni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957731/ivarni) mentioned you are able to change what delimiters [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) uses to interpolate values. For example you can pass the following regex to underscore to switch the delimiters to mustache style delimiters which should work in your case.

```
 _.templateSettings = {
       evaluate: /\{\[([\s\S]+?)\]\}/g,
       interpolate: /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g, 
       escape: /\{\{-([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
 };
```

You would then modify your template to something like this

```
  <script type="text/template" id="amazon-result-item-view">
      <p class="small-text">
      <a href="{{ url }}" target="_blank" >
      {[ name.substring(0,30) ]}...
      </a></p>

      <img width="100" src="{{ image_url }}" />
      <button data-product-index="{{ cid }}"
       class="tiny add-amazon-product">
      Add product</button>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using JSP syntax `<%= %>` instead of php syntax `{[ whatever ]}`. In this case, your 4th line should be like this:

```
{[ name.substring(0,30) ]}
```